# Some keys not working after VMware crash

Tags: windows-7, windows

I was running another OS in VMware and after a while everything froze so I was forced to restart my computer by manually pressing the restart button. After the restart some keys on my keyboard started to not work. At first it was only CTRL but now I cant use p,[,0,- and / either. Every once in a while, out of nowhere some of the keys become active for a short period of time. I tried with another keyboard and have the same results...so it is not a keyboard malfunction.

The on-screen keyboard works, but being a programmer I use CTRL a lot.

Any suggestions what I should try? thanks.